# How can I re-organize the page order in SQL Server (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am in the process of trying to develop a "Article" based system, There can be one Article entry in the database, then as many article data linking to that ArticleData.

Right now I am trying to update the PageOrder correctly.  I want the numbers to always be consistent as in 1 to 15 for example.  I don't want page numbers to go like this.  1, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10... It should just be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

I have managed to complete when adding a new record for the article, as I insert a new record and then recalculate the ordering successfully.  The problem is when I want to change the offical record.  For example:

Lets say I have 5 Pages.
 - Page 1,
 - Page 2,
 - Page 3,
 - Page 4,
 - Page 5

Lets say I want Page 3 to become Page 5
 - Page 1,
 - Page 2,
 - Page 4,
 - Page 5,
 - Page 3

Now the indexing I want to be able to reindex this so that it becomes Like what it should be.

The question is now... How can I do this within a T-SQL procedure (SQL Server 2005)?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_InsertOrUpdateArticle]
    @Id int = null
    ,@ArticleId int = null
    ,@Header varchar(50)
    ,@ParentId int = null
    ,@ArticleType int
    ,@DisplayOrder int = 0
    ,@Content text
    ,@ModifiedById int
    ,@ModifiedBy varchar(50)
    ,@ModifiedDate datetime
    ,@Subject varchar(100)
    ,@NewPage int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE 
        [Article]
        SET
            [Header] = @Header
            ,[ParentId] = @ParentId
            ,[DisplayOrder] = @DisplayOrder
            ,[Type] = @ArticleType
        WHERE
            [Article].[Id] = @ArticleId

    -- If Article does not exists then we don't have any record of even Article Data!
    -- NEW RECORD!
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO [Article]
            (
                [Header]
                ,[ParentId]
                ,[DisplayOrder]
                ,[Type]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @Header
                ,@ParentId
                ,@DisplayOrder
                ,@ArticleType
            );

            INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
            (
                [ArticleId]
                ,[Content]
                ,[CreatedBy]
                ,[CreatedById]
                ,[ModifiedBy]
                ,[ModifiedById]
                ,[PostDate]
                ,[ModifiedDate]
                ,[Subject]
                ,[PageOrder]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @@IDENTITY
                ,@Content
                ,@ModifiedBy
                ,@ModifiedById
                ,@ModifiedBy
                ,@ModifiedById
                ,@ModifiedDate
                ,@ModifiedDate
                ,@Subject
                ,1 -- First Page!!!
            )

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            -- We do have a Article Record, therefore we update the current page and check to see if it is a new page!
            UPDATE 
                [ArticleData]
                SET
                    [Content] = @Content
                    ,[Subject] = @Subject
                    ,[ModifiedBy] = @ModifiedBy
                    ,[ModifiedById] = @ModifiedById
                    ,[ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate
                WHERE
                    [ArticleData].[Id] = @Id AND
                    [ArticleData].[ArticleId] = @ArticleId

            -- Are we a new Article Data?
            IF( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 )
            BEGIN   

                -- We are lets check to see if the page we want this article for exists
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT [PageOrder] FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId AND [PageOrder] = @NewPage )
                BEGIN

                    -- It does exists therefore we need to reorder the pages
                    UPDATE 
                        [ArticleData] 
                        SET 
                            [PageOrder] = A.PageOrder + 1
                            FROM [ArticleData] A 
                        WHERE 
                            A.PageOrder >= @NewPage AND 
                            [ArticleId] = @ArticleId

                    -- We now Insert The New data that we want at that page
                    INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
                    (
                        [ArticleId]
                        ,[Content]
                        ,[CreatedBy]
                        ,[CreatedById]
                        ,[ModifiedBy]
                        ,[ModifiedById]
                        ,[PostDate]
                        ,[ModifiedDate]
                        ,[Subject]
                        ,[PageOrder]
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        @ArticleId
                        ,@Content
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@Subject
                        ,@NewPage
                    )   

                END     
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                    -- Since that page we want to add is not in reach we will simply add it to the very last page                   
                    INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
                    (
                        [ArticleId]
                        ,[Content]
                        ,[CreatedBy]
                        ,[CreatedById]
                        ,[ModifiedBy]
                        ,[ModifiedById]
                        ,[PostDate]
                        ,[ModifiedDate]
                        ,[Subject]
                        ,[PageOrder]
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        @ArticleId
                        ,@Content
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@Subject
                        ,(SELECT COUNT(Id)+1 FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId) -- Add new Page as Last Record
                    )   

                END     

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                -- The article did update therefore lets reorder our pages based on the new page defined
                -- Does this page in the article exists?  IF it does lets update the pages
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT [PageOrder] FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId AND [PageOrder] = @NewPage )
                BEGIN

                    -- Update all pages with new numbers 
                    UPDATE 
                        [ArticleData] 
                        SET 
                            [PageOrder] = A.PageOrder + 1
                            FROM [ArticleData] A 
                        WHERE 
                            A.PageOrder >= @NewPage AND 
                            [ArticleId] = @ArticleId

                    -- Update THIS article data with the new page number
                    UPDATE 
                    [ArticleData]
                    SET
                        [PageOrder] = @NewPage
                    WHERE
                        [ArticleData].[Id] = @Id AND
                        [ArticleData].[ArticleId] = @ArticleId

                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                    -- Page doesn't exists because what we want to change it to is to far out of range for example if there are only 5 pages, then the ordering will simply set this page to the last index
                    UPDATE 
                    [ArticleData]
                    SET
                        [PageOrder] = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [Id] = @Id AND [ArticleId] = @ArticleId)
                    WHERE
                        [ArticleData].[Id] = @Id AND
                        [ArticleData].[ArticleId] = @ArticleId

                END

            END

        END

END
```

Comment: I don't think trying to keep those order numbers sequential really makes a lot of sense - you're only causing lots of unnecessary updates.... extra tip: don't use  1,2,3,4  for page order - rather use 10,20,30,40 - then you leave yourself some room to "squeeze in" a new page in the middle between two existing ones without having to renumber lots of pages!  If you really need a sequential number for your pages in their correct order, you can always look at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ....) ` constructs which do this automagically for you...

Comment: Oh the page numbers are completely done automatically based on by sending what page number the new page is.  if the Article and ArticleData exists already then its going to just update the pageorder with that new pageorder number.  Worst case scenario I'll have to do this all in code...

Comment: what you are trying to do does not make any sense, because, it is all 'not in order' on disk so to speak, so all you need to do is to write a query that will do an order by for you. Otherwise, make your Page Number your primary key, because the physical layout of the table is determined by the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renumbering pages is relatively simple, but I can't tell whether you're wanting to slot this into your existing code, in which case, not sure where this would go:

```
DECLARE @OldPageID int
DECLARE @NewPageID int

set @OldPageID = 3
set @NewPageID = 5

UPDATE
    Page
SET
    PageID = CASE
        WHEN PageID = @OldPageID THEN @NewPageID ELSE
        WHEN @OldPageID < @NewPageID THEN PageID -1 ELSE PageID + 1 END
where
    PageID between
        CASE WHEN @OldPageID < @NewPageID THEN @OldPageID ELSE @NewPageID END
        and
        CASE WHEN @OldPageID < @NewPageID THEN @NewPageID ELSE @OldPageID END
```

Comment: Thanks a million bro... I'll post my entire thing just to see where I put it =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final result that works

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_InsertOrUpdateArticle]
    @Id int = null
    ,@ArticleId int = null
    ,@Header varchar(50)
    ,@ParentId int = null
    ,@ArticleType int
    ,@DisplayOrder int = 0
    ,@Content text
    ,@ModifiedById int
    ,@ModifiedBy varchar(50)
    ,@ModifiedDate datetime
    ,@Subject varchar(100)
    ,@NewPage int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE 
        [Article]
        SET
            [Header] = @Header
            ,[ParentId] = @ParentId
            ,[DisplayOrder] = @DisplayOrder
            ,[Type] = @ArticleType
        WHERE
            [Article].[Id] = @ArticleId

    -- If Article does not exists then we don't have any record of even Article Data!
    -- NEW RECORD!
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO [Article]
            (
                [Header]
                ,[ParentId]
                ,[DisplayOrder]
                ,[Type]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @Header
                ,@ParentId
                ,@DisplayOrder
                ,@ArticleType
            );

            INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
            (
                [ArticleId]
                ,[Content]
                ,[CreatedBy]
                ,[CreatedById]
                ,[ModifiedBy]
                ,[ModifiedById]
                ,[PostDate]
                ,[ModifiedDate]
                ,[Subject]
                ,[PageOrder]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @@IDENTITY
                ,@Content
                ,@ModifiedBy
                ,@ModifiedById
                ,@ModifiedBy
                ,@ModifiedById
                ,@ModifiedDate
                ,@ModifiedDate
                ,@Subject
                ,1 -- First Page!!!
            )

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            -- We do have a Article Record, therefore we update the current page and check to see if it is a new page!
            UPDATE 
                [ArticleData]
                SET
                    [Content] = @Content
                    ,[Subject] = @Subject
                    ,[ModifiedBy] = @ModifiedBy
                    ,[ModifiedById] = @ModifiedById
                    ,[ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate
                WHERE
                    [ArticleData].[Id] = @Id AND
                    [ArticleData].[ArticleId] = @ArticleId

            -- Are we a new Article Data?
            IF( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 )
            BEGIN   

                -- We are lets check to see if the page we want this article for exists
                IF EXISTS ( SELECT [PageOrder] FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId AND [PageOrder] = @NewPage )
                BEGIN

                    -- It does exists therefore we need to reorder the pages
                    UPDATE 
                        [ArticleData] 
                        SET 
                            [PageOrder] = A.PageOrder + 1
                            FROM [ArticleData] A 
                        WHERE 
                            A.PageOrder >= @NewPage AND 
                            [ArticleId] = @ArticleId

                    -- We now Insert The New data that we want at that page
                    INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
                    (
                        [ArticleId]
                        ,[Content]
                        ,[CreatedBy]
                        ,[CreatedById]
                        ,[ModifiedBy]
                        ,[ModifiedById]
                        ,[PostDate]
                        ,[ModifiedDate]
                        ,[Subject]
                        ,[PageOrder]
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        @ArticleId
                        ,@Content
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@Subject
                        ,@NewPage
                    )   

                END     
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                    -- Since that page we want to add is not in reach we will simply add it to the very last page                   
                    INSERT INTO [ArticleData]
                    (
                        [ArticleId]
                        ,[Content]
                        ,[CreatedBy]
                        ,[CreatedById]
                        ,[ModifiedBy]
                        ,[ModifiedById]
                        ,[PostDate]
                        ,[ModifiedDate]
                        ,[Subject]
                        ,[PageOrder]
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        @ArticleId
                        ,@Content
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedBy
                        ,@ModifiedById
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@ModifiedDate
                        ,@Subject
                        ,(SELECT COUNT(Id)+1 FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId) -- Add new Page as Last Record
                    )   

                END     

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                -- The article did update therefore lets reorder our pages based on the new page defined        
                DECLARE @OldPage int
                SET @OldPage = (SELECT [PageOrder] FROM [ArticleData] WHERE [ArticleId] = @ArticleId AND [Id] = @Id) -- Get the old Page from the Id we have

                IF ( @OldPage != @NewPage )
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE
                        [ArticleData]
                    SET
                        PageOrder = CASE
                                WHEN PageOrder = @OldPage THEN @NewPage
                                WHEN @OldPage < @NewPage THEN PageOrder -1 ELSE PageOrder + 1 END
                    WHERE
                        PageOrder BETWEEN
                            CASE WHEN @OldPage < @NewPage THEN @OldPage ELSE @NewPage END
                            AND
                            CASE WHEN @OldPage < @NewPage THEN @NewPage ELSE @OldPage END
                END

            END

        END

END
```